# RSpec raising exception when validating presence

Tags: ruby, validation, rspec, associations, rspec2

I've got one model (Discussion) that has_one of another model (Visibility).  There's a `before_validation :on => :create` call for the Discussion model that is setting a value on `visibility`, i.e.:

```
class Discussion
  has_one :visibility

  validates_presence_of :some_unrelated_field

  before_validation :set_visibility_relationship, :on => :create

  private

  def set_visibility_relationship
    visibility.some_entity = self.the_same_entity
  end
end
```

I then have the following in my `discussion_spec.rb`:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:some_unrelated_field) }
```

The before_validation is throwing an error:

```
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :some_unrelated_field }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visibility.some_entity' for #<Discussion:0x007ff6ebc43170>
```

If I comment out either the `before_validation` call or the `should validate_presence_of` for the unrelated field, all my tests pass.

I tried to step through with pry, and I found that one of the error keys being set on discussion.errors was "visibility.some_entity", while all the other keys were attribute based, e.g.: "some_unrelated_field".  It seems like there might be some bug in rspec that is causing this error to be thrown, but I could just be doing something wrong as well.

Comment: Is there a `has_one :visibility` line inside your Discussion model?

Comment: There is, sorry I left that out of the code.  Edited to include it in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's actually an issue with shoulda-matchers 2.0.0.  Upgrading to version 2.2.0 fixed the problem.